# Experiencing Latency with Azure Hostpool's Remote Desktop for Graphics-Intensive Application

Tags: azure, remote-desktop

I have set up an Azure Hostpool with NC8as T4 v3 VMs to host a graphics-intensive application called CostX, similar to a CAD application. However, I am encountering a significant issue with latency. When using Remote Desktop to access the application, the latency is quite high. Interestingly, when I use our RMM called Ninja to log in, the latency is manageable.

**Attempted Solution:**
I have followed the steps outlined in this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/virtual-desktop/enable-gpu-acceleration.md to enable GPU acceleration in an attempt to resolve the issue. Despite this, the latency problem persists when using Remote Desktop.

**Expected Outcome:**
I expected that following the steps to enable GPU acceleration would improve the performance of Remote Desktop and reduce latency. However, this has not been the case.

**Request:**
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights into what I could check or modify to improve Remote Desktop performance for this graphics-intensive application. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue and found a solution?